# Regex to match one or two quotes but not three in a row

Tags: regex, string, quotes

For the life of me I can't figure this one out.

I need to search the following text, matching only the quotes in bold:

> Don't match: """This is a python docstring"""
>
> Match: **"** This is a regular string **"**
>
> Match: **""** ← That is an empty string

How can I do this with a regular expression?

Here's what I've tried:

**Doesn't work**:

```
(?!"")"(?<!"")
```

Close, but doesn't match double quotes.

**Doesn't work**:

```
"(?<!""")|(?!"")"(?<!"")|(?!""")"
```

I naively thought that I could add the alternates that I don't want but the logic ends up reversed. This one matches everything because all quotes match at least one of the alternates.

*(Please note: I'm not running the code, so solutions around using `__doc__` won't help, I'm just trying to find and replace in my code editor.)*

Answer (score 27):

You can use `/(?<!")"{1,2}(?!")/`

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/sq5LZC/1)

**Autopsy**:

- `(?<!")` a negative look-behind for the literal `"`. The match *cannot* have this character in front
- `"{1,2}` the literal `"` matched once or twice
- `(?!")` a negative look-ahead for the literal `"`. The match *cannot* have this character after

Your first try might've failed because `(?!")` is a negative *look-ahead*, and `(?<!")` is a negative *look-behind*. It makes no sense to have look-aheads before your match, or look-behinds after your match.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Great, thanks!  Actually, it sometimes makes sense to have lookaheads before a match, to make exclude (or include) possible matches. In my case, I was seeing if I could make use of it to look at the full set, but it didn't add any value.

Comment: I just realized that I needed to only match a single quote character at a time.  Please check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20643701/143295)... you helped me get there.  I didn't change the original question because you answered it perfectly (and I didn't want to ask a new question that was so similar).

Comment: @NickC No worries. Let's hope someone else can use this answer one day. :)

Answer (score 3):

I realized that my original problem description was actually slightly wrong. That is, I need to actually **only match a *single* quote character**, unless if it's part of a group of *3* quote characters.

The difference is that this is desirable for editing so that I can find and replace with `'`.  If I match *"one or two quotes"* then I can't automatically replace with a single character.

I came up with this modification to [h20000000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20642907/143295) that satisfies that case:

```
(?<!"")(?<=(?!""").)"(?!"")
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

In the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kO2vK7), you can see that the `""` are matched individually, instead of as a group.

This works very similarly to the other answer, except:

- it only matches a single `"`
- that leaves us with matching everything we want except it **still matches the middle quotes of a `"""`**:

  [image]
- Finally, adding the `(?<=(?!""").)` excludes that case specifically, by saying "look back one character, then fail the match if the next three characters are `"""`):

  [image]

---

I decided not to change the question because I don't want to hijack the answer, but I think this can be a useful addition.